# Is it true that a monotic, differentiable function with non-zero derivative has a continuous inverse?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that a strictly monotic, differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ with non-zero derivative has a continuous inverse?
This is a small caveat in a problem I'm working on, if this is true then I'm all good.

Comment: by monotonic, do you mean $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)$?

Comment: yes, or with the < all as >. Maybe it is required that the derivative be non-zero? -- I edited in "strictly" to give this. @IttayWeiss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something stronger is true. A strictly monotone and continuous function on $\mathbb R $ has a continuous inverse. The function doesn't even have to have a derivative.